# Why is Django User being AnonymousUser when I make a request from a JS client but it is properly set when using Django Rest Framework ?

Tags: python, django, session, authentication, django-rest-framework

I'm having an issue when trying to get the information of the user that is logged in in Django. My Login service looks like this:

```
username = request.data['username']
password = request.data['password']
user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
if user is not None:
     if user.is_active:
           login(request, user)
```

It's currently working properly at least when using Django Rest Framework
(It even appears at the top right the user that is logged in).

I'm trying to bring the profile of the user that is logged in so I developed a profile service which tries to get the user logged in which is working perfectly when using Django Rest Framework.

The issue comes when I try to call the same endpoint from a JS client. I think it might be an issue with setting something in the header after the Django login is executed. Currently, I am not doing anything in my JS client but to call to the login endpoint which is returning properly. Should I set a cookie or something in the header of each request so Django knows which user am I? If so, how should it be that ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

> Should I set a cookie or something in the header of each request so Django knows which user am I? If so, how should it be that ?

You definitively need the session cookie to be passed.

By default, it'll be [`sessionid`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/settings/#session-cookie-name)

Comment: Where should the sessionid be set? How could I set this in the JS client?

Comment: I don't know JS much and this will likely depend on how you perform the request.